# Limit of infinite product involving $e$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I have a solution of an exercise I really don't understand. Taking the sequence:
$$ p_1 = 1, p_2 = (2/1)^2, p_3 = (3/2)^3, \ldots p_n = (n/(n-1))^n $$

Then $p_n \rightarrow e$. Also it is:
$$ \frac{p_1p_2 \cdots p_n}{n} = \frac{n^n}{n!} $$

So far, so good.

But then it concludes that **therefore** $(n^n/n!)^{1/n} \rightarrow e$ as well.

I can't figure out this apparent triviality, I proved it using Stirling, but not using the fact that $p_n \rightarrow e$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{n^n}{n!}}=\frac{\sqrt[n]{p_1\ldots p_n}}{\sqrt[n]n}.$$But, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n=e$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{p_1\ldots p_n}=e$, too. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]n=1$, it follows that, indeed, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{n^n}{n!}}=e$.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't see why $(p_1 \cdots p_n)^{1/n} \rightarrow p_n$, I think I understand now. This limit is equivalent to the limit  of $(p_k \cdots p_n)^{1/n}$, for any given $k$, as for the first, fixed $k-$terms: $(p_k \cdots p_n)^{1/n} \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't see why $(p_1 \cdots p_n)^{1/n} \rightarrow p_n$, I think I understand now. This limit is equivalent to the limit  of $(p_k \cdots p_n)^{1/n}$, for any given $k$, as for the first, fixed $k-$terms: $(p_k \cdots p_n)^{1/n}\rightarrow 1$. Then since $p_n \rightarrow e$, $k$ can be chosen big enough that all term $p_i$ with $i>k$ are close to $e$ as desired, and so the limit $(p_k \cdots p_n)^{1/n} \rightarrow (e^n)^{1/n} \rightarrow e$. I'm wonder if there is a more elegant way to proof this (even using $\Log$ as in the other answer.

Comment: The elegant way consists in using logarithms, together with the following theorem: if $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=l$, then$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}n=l.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\ln (p_n)\to 1$ we get $\frac {\ln (p_1)+\ln (p_2)+\cdots+\ln (p_n)} n \to 1$. This gives $\frac {\ln (p_1p_2\cdots p_n)} {n} \to 1$ or $\ln (p_1p_2\cdots p_n)^{1/n} \to 1$ from which the conclusion follows.